# How to save message as msg using exchange webservices

Tags: exchangewebservices, msg

My requirement is to get all email messages from certain mailbox on Exchange 2010 server. I need to save all attachments and the messages itself to the file system. I have no problem retrieving and saving the attachments, but the only wat EWS will allow me to save the message is as a .eml file. These files are going into a document repository system that will display .msg files, but not .eml files. 
I am using a Web Service application to retrieve the emails and attachments using EWS. I use a console application to call the Web Service and then complete the process for the files to go into the document repository system.
I thought about converting the .eml files to .msg, but can't find a way to do that.
I thought about getting an id of the message in the web service and using that id in the console app using outlook interop to retrieve the message file and save it as .msg, but can't find an id that match in both EWS and outlook interop.

I do not have the option to use third party code or tools.

I think my set up is flexible, but just can't find a way to get these messages to the file system as .msg files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

tshaffer

Answer (score 0):

This is solution with EWS and .msg file format. It uses third party API, but works great 
http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices/tutorial/downloadmessagetomsgfile.html